# Is this a visa refusal stamp?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for my wife's visa as a student dependant. She had earlier applied for UK visit visa in 2004 and 2008. In both cases, they did not pursue the case when asked for further documents and case was closed. Her 2004 passport does not have any stamp on it but the 2008 one has a stamp of Uk on the last page. They do not have access to application or emails from back then nor do they remember.
Can anyone please confirm if this is a rejection stamp? I talked to a solicitor in UK and he mentioned that this is not a refusal stamp and not to mention it. However, local agents believe this is a rejection.
Can anyone help in understanding what this stamp actually is?
Thannkyou[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not pursue the case when asked for further documents" ?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, further documents were required and they decided not to continue with the application anymore and the passports were returned. There is no access to documents from back then and this is all I know.

Comment: Don't know what documents were required or if this is a case of visa rejection or visa withdrawal.

Comment: Did you receive any letter similar to this - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95865/uk-visa-refusal-due-to-misinterpretation

Comment: That is the problem that no one remembers as this is from about 15 years back. It could have been confirmed if they knew or remembered any letter. What does this stamp on the last page of passport signify?

Comment: Why are you asking on here if an actual lawyer has told you it's not a problem? If you've been told contrary information, refer back to your lawyer.

Comment: @M.AmmanAamir When you said "they decided not to ..." do you mean 
your wife?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is a refusal stamp according to this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87808/118049).

You will likely need to disclose the exact reason of the refusal on new applications, if you don't have the letter anymore, you can do a [SAR](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration) (Subject Access Request) to have the data held by UKVI (UK Visas and Immigration) communicated back to you and get a copy of that refusal letter.

The procedure is explained on the link above

Comment: SAR requires UK postcode. I tried doing it as well but I am based in Pakistan

Comment: @M.AmmanAamir Email subjectaccessrequest@homeoffice.gov.uk if you have issues filling the SAR

Comment: I'm not sure why you think an answer on Travel.SE would be more authoritative than an actual lawyer...

Comment: Why does OP need the letter? Couldn't UK authorities look up the refusal reason on their own? I presume you could just type in "unable to recollect refusal reason" in the visa form.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater The answer referred to was written by a sadly deceased contributor who was *extremely* knowledgeable about UK immigration law.

Comment: @lambshaanxy deceased or not... I'm sure an immigration lawyer is also "extremely knowledgeable" about UK immigration law and it's generally an awful idea to override the opinion of an actual lawyer with one sourced on an internet forum

Comment: @ScottishTapWater In general you'd be right, but in this particular case the OP's lawyer appears to be quite clearly wrong (or the OP has misrepresented the situation and/or their answer somehow).  And for what it's worth, Gayot is quoting his own lawyers in his response.

Comment: At which point, the OP should go ask another lawyer... Not a random internet forum